# parameter being same name as javascript default method

Tags: javascript

Would there be any problem if a code is written like this with same parameter and method name? It doesn't seem to have problem when used as string in addClass(), what about other situation?

```
var hi = function(next) {
    target.next().addClass(next);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem because first `next` occurence is a function parameter and second `target.next()` is method of `target` object. You cannot call `target.next()` without dot notation so there isn't any conflict.

Comment: To complete the answer, if it wasn t a method of target, js would search variable name on his scope, if ot do not find anything, the parent scope, and keep going searching on parent's parent,... if still not found it

Answer (score 0):

It has semantic or logical problem if `addClass` does not interested in a function as its parameter

Comment: I used addClass just for string example.